# center and position elements in CSS

Tags: css, html, background-image, css-position

I'm stuck with my HTML/CSS code where I need to **horizontally center** two divs (A, B) with background images in one absolutely positioned div (C).

Bering in mind that:

- bottom edge of larger div (A) needs to be at the bottom of (C).
- top edge of (A) needs to be at the top edge of (B).
- (B) needs to be behind (A) - which needs the same `position` property, I think.
- number of added inner div elements to the (C) div is not restricted

Here is my fiddle where I managed to position the (A) div inside the (C) http://jsfiddle.net/meridius/DGexR/ But no matter what I do, I can't accomplish the rest.

**EDIT:**
Here is how it should look like [image]

**Code preview:**
*For working example (with background images) please see above mentioned fiddle.*

HTML

```
<div class="desk">
    <div class="figure">        
        <div class="type sprites-sachy sprite-WKing"></div>
        <div class="special sprites-sachy sprite-halo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.desk { /* this class must not be touched */
    position: absolute; 
    top: 129px; 
    left: 202px;    
    border: 1px solid #FF0000; 
    width: 65px;    
    height: 65px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
.figure {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
.type {
    margin-left:-50%;
    z-index:2;
}
.special {
    border: 1px solid #008000;
    z-index:1;
  /*   display:none; uncomment this to see .figurka centered how it is supposed to */
}
```

---

***NOTE:***
*I'd like to avoid this question being closed as too localized, so let me state first that I believe that I'm not the only one having problems positioning (and centering) elements in CSS.*

Comment: Include your code in your question please.

Comment: _“I believe that I'm not the only one having problems positioning (and centering) elements in CSS”_ – well, you’re not the first one asking about this either. There’s lots ans lots of discussions about various techniques of centering elements with CSS on the web.

Comment: Any chance you can create that in Paint and link the image?  Having trouble picturing what it is your desired look is.

Comment: Could you post an image of what the expected result should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `display: none` or `position: absolute`, `.special` is taken out of the flow and `.type` is centered properly.

To center `.special` horizontally as well, you can use a technique from [CSS-TRICKS: Centering Percentage Width/Height Elements](http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/): move it to the top and half the width to the left

```
.special {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

The only item left is moving `.special` behind `.type` with `z-index: -1`.

See full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGexR/2/)

Since you know that the width of `.sprite-halo` is `78px`, you can always use pixel values, of course

```
.special {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -39px;
}
```

See also @Bipin Kumar Pal's answer.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGexR/6/)

Comment: This is awesome, it is exactly what I wanted to achieve! I'm a little afraid of the `transform` property which is experimental and IE supports it only from v9 and above. I hope I will be able to convince a few people, I know of using v8 on WinXP, to switch to some more mature browser. If you happen to know how to achieve the same result without the `transform`, I'd be more than grateful. If you don't, thank you anyway.

Comment: I don't like @Bipin Kumar Pal's answer because he hardsets the .special{left} in px. I'd much rather see it in percents because the application uses different .special images and I don't want to handset halve of width for every one of them.

Answer (score 0):

So you got this structure:

```
<div class="desk">
    <div class="figure">
        <div class="type"></div>
        <div class="special"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Make sure .desk is absolute or relative positioned (which you did). Please note that a float won't do anything. For now I suppose .type is 200px h/200px w and .special is 150px h/150px w.

```
.desk { position: absolute; .. }
.desk .figure { position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 200px; bottom: 0; left: 50%; margin-left: -100px; }
.desk .type { position: absolute; z-index: 2; margin-left: -100px; left: 50%; top: 0; }
.desk .special { position: absolute; z-index: 1; margin-left: -75px; left: 50%; top: 0; }
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I "fiddled" your solution http://jsfiddle.net/meridius/Ndhr8/ and as you can see it's just a mess. Also I'd like to avoid using dimensions in px and use percents instead.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle a bit and it works like a charm. Keep in mind that absolute positioned elements should have dimension. I introduced .type and .special to be a new wrapper in which the sprites you used are contained in. Now you can just use margin: auto to center these items. You still need some fixed dimensions though.

Comment: I just saw the fiddle wasn't updated; made changes again and updated it. Does this work for you?

Comment: I'm sorry but your result is not quite like the picture (see updated question). In my original fiddle I wrote that the `.desk` class must not be touched, that is because I use it like jQueryUI Draggable which needs to `tolerance:"fit"` to jQueryUI Droppable. Yet, your solution relies on its changed dimensions. That's why I can't accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.sprite-halo{ background-position: 0 -1700px; width: 78px; height: 12px; background-color:darkgreen; position:absolute; top:0; left:-40px; z-index:-5;}
```

please use this code. My side working.